# Good Regex for copy file base on folder name

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a good regex to achieve this in C# :

Based on a folder + filename, I want to copy the filename to a new name.

Example :

> Input : C:\Test\Sample_Value1\File1.txt
>   Output : C:\otherFolder\File1_value1.txt

-> When I find Value1 in the path, I want to copy the file to another location with the name of the file set to File1_Value1.txt.

> Input : C:\Test\Sample_Value2\OtherFile.txt
>   Output : C:\otherFolder\OtherFile_Value2.txt

-> When I find Value2 in the path, I want to copy the file to another location with the name of the file set to OtherFile_Value2.txt

The "Value1" "Value2" can be static value in my code. I will have a list of 'value' to search like this.

Any idea ?

Comment: ...as opposed to a _bad_ regex for this? Why do you believe regex will help here?

Comment: You don't need a regex, check out [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

So maybe a simple approach would work:

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(input);
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
var ext = Path.GetExtension(input);
var output = "";

if (dir.Contains("_Value1"))
{
    output = Path.Combine(@"C:\otherFolder", string.Format("{0}_Value1{2}",
        fileName, ext));
}
```

That same code works for `Value2` as well. Clearly this could be put into an extension method and accept a couple parameters and made dynamic.

I can't see any compelling reason here for a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^C:\\Test\\.*?_(.*?)\\(.*?)\.(.*?)$", @"C:\otherFolder\$2_$1.$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the character string “C:” literally (case sensitive) «C:»
Match the backslash character «\\»
Match the character string “Test” literally (case sensitive) «Test»
Match the backslash character «\\»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the backslash character «\\»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) «$»

C:\otherFolder\$2_$1.$3

Insert the character string “C:” literally «C:»
Insert the backslash character «\»
Insert the character string “otherFolder” literally «otherFolder»
Insert the backslash character «\»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 «$2»
Insert the character “_” literally «_»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the character “.” literally «.»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 3 «$3»
```

Comment: Was this text explanation of the regex generated or did you type this out? Curious

Comment: Where can I find this resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"C:\this\is\my\myvalue\test.txt";
string lookingfor = "myvalue";

        if (input.Contains(lookingfor))
        {
            //Format new name
           string newdir = @"C:\newdir\" + Path.GetFileName(input) + "_" + lookingfor;
           Trace.WriteLine(newdir);
           //Copy/Move Logic here using File.Copy()
           File.Copy(input, newdir);
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
```

With the information that you seem to already have you do not need a regex but you can tackle it in this way.

Grab the stuff you need and just reformat the string yourself as below and then use `File.Copy` to move the file.